# Writing a set of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, article-writing

Let

- $A$ be a countable set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$
- $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a bijection
- $O= \{x_k:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid k\in [1,\dots, K]\subset \mathbb{Z}\}$, for some $K$ and some given functions $x_k$.

I want to define a set $R$ which contain functions $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, g(n)= i$ if $x(n) \in f^{-1}(i)$, where $x\in O$.

I believe that I can write the set $R$ like this

$$
R = \left\{g:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}, g(n)= i \text{ if } x(n)\in f^{-1}(i) \mid x\in O\right\}.
$$
but I'm also considering to write the set like this
$$
R = \left\{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mapsto i \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ if } x(n)\in f^{-1}(i) \mid x\in O \right\},
$$
avoiding the introduction of the symbol $g$. Are these ways of writing understandable? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Formally, a set is written in the form $\{x \:|\: P(x) \}$ with $P(x)$ describing the properties of a set $x$ to be contained in the set in question. Of course, this is relaxed a bit in practice (for example writing $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \:|\: x^2 \geq 2\}$ instead of $\{x \:|\: x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x^2 \geq 2\}$ or even $\{x^2 \:|\: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ instead of $\{y \:|\: \text{ there exists } x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } y = x^2\}$  ), but in general,  the properties your elements have to satisfy should still all come after the bar, i.e. $R = \{g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \:|\: ...\}$.

Your description of $R$ is not completely clear, there are two possible in
terpretations coming to my mind:

1. a) We have $g \in R$ if there exists $x \in O$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ if we have $g(n) = i$, then $x(n) \in f^{-1}(i)$.

   b) We have $g \in R$ if there exists $x \in O$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $x(n) \in f^{-1}(g(n))$.
2. a)  We have $g \in R$ if for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ if we have $g(n) = i$, then there exists $x \in O$ such that  we have $x(n) \in f^{-1}(i)$.

   b)  We have $g \in R$ if for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists $x \in O$ such that  we have $x(n) \in f^{-1}(g(n))$.

(the descriptions 1 a) and b) describe the same set as do 2 a) and 2 b), the a) parts are more in the flavor you used in your question, whereas the b) parts are a bit shorter)

If one of these two adequately describes what you want, then you can just take the part of the sentence beginning after *if* and write the part behind the bar, i.e. $R = \{g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \:|\: \text{ there exists } x \in O ...\}$.